# How to pass kernel module as namelist file to libkvm when getting information from kernel crash vmcores

Tags: freebsd

I have a utility that uses the -M [either /dev/kmem or vmcore] and -N [namelist file (kernel.debug)] option to extract information from kernel crash vmcores, similar to how utilities like "vmstat" work on vmcores using the -M/-N option

```
usage: vmstat [-afHhimPsz] [-c count] [-M core [-N system]] [-w wait]
vmstat -m -M vmcore -N kernel.debug
```

But after moving some bits out of the kernel into a kernel module, now has the symbols outside of the kernel.debug. So now I cannot just pass the utility -M vmcore -N kernel.debug options because the symbols are now in the kernel module. Can libkvm be tweaked to process the kernel module in addition to the kernel.debug file?

For illustrating...I want to

utility -M vmcore -N (kernel.debug + kernel module)

--
Shrikanth R K

Answer (score 0):

Could you use `kgdb`(1)? Because recent versions load module symbols automatically.

Otherwise, if you want to do it manually, you will need to walk the `linker_files` list, starting at `linker_files->tqh_first` and following the `link.tqe_next` pointers until you find the entry with the filename you are looking for. The address member of that entry is the load address of the module. Using `nm <module.ko> | grep ' t '` you can find the names and symbol offsets in a module. Add the module's load address and the symbol's offset and you have the address of the symbol.